# iterate the cpu active run queue list sched.h

Tags: linux, list, kernel

I 'm trying to do some changing at the `sched.h` of the linux kernel. The default code has `struct rq *rq` which is the active run queue list and I need to iterate the run queue list rq for each process p. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

In the linux kernel source code there is a pointer &init_task.It points to your first task in the runqueue.
Declare a structure of type task_struct to &init_task. Then use a while loop and keep the terminating condition as until you reach the same task back